# Mixing stores in same Xodus Environment

Tags: xodus

Would it be possible to use a PersistentEntityStore and one or more plain Store instances in the same Environment instance? I was hoping to use transactions that cover changes on such a combination. 
I see potential conflicts with store names that I would have to avoid.  Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to mix code using different API layers inside a single transaction. The only requirement is the data touched by different API should be isolated, disjoint sets of names of `Stores` should be used.

What are the names of `Stores` used by `PersistentEntityStore`? Any `PersistentEntityStore` has its own unique name, and names of all `Stores`, that represent mapping of the entity store to key/value layer, start with `"${PersistentEntityStore name}."`, as it's specified in the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/entity-store/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/StoreNamingRules.java#L140).

Another issue is that API is not complete for such approach. After a `StoreTransaction` is created against the `PersistentEntityStore`, it should be be cast to `PersistentStoreTransaction` in order to call `PersistentStoreTransaction#getEnvironmentTransaction()` for getting underlying transaction:

```
final StoreTransaction txn = entityStore.beginTransaction();
// here is underlying Transaction instance:
final Transaction envTxn = ((PersistentStoreTransaction) txn).getEnvironmentTransaction();
```